# Do privilege reputation requirements mean feedback on the new user experience is being lost?

Tags: discussion, reputation, privileges, feedback

**The Question**

Are there user stories where feedback on the new user experience could be being lost due to reputation requirements and, if there are, is there any way to improve the situation without undermining the intentions of such a system?

I want to state that I understand **why** privileges are gated behind reputation thresholds (to prevent sock puppet accounts and bots). This question is somewhat ironically meta in itself - being a form of feedback driven by my own personal experience.

---

**Context**

As an example, I was curious about whether my votes are actually recorded as I find the "but your feedback has been recorded." message to be ambiguous and vague. That led me to [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/330254/make-the-message-shown-to-registered-users-without-enough-reputation-to-vote-les) which I see is where the updated message has come from. If I wanted to reply to the existing discussion in a comment, I first need 5 reputation. Not wanting to jump through hoops or incorrectly reply indirectly via a separate answer, my feedback is then lost.

Similarly, I've been using Stack Overflow for years now and in all that time I still don't even have 15 reputation required to cast votes. I can almost always find an answer to what I'm looking for or a better idea so I just "vote" and move on. As someone who cares about quality and good practice, I don't intend to post low effort questions for the sake of gaining reputation and I find it hard to find questions I can answer that haven't already been or aren't just duplicates.

In a sense, it feels as though the reputation system is encouraging me (as a "new" user) to either not engage with the site or to just post low effort questions/answers in the hopes of gaining enough reputation to where I can engage with the site as intended. Until this moment, I've had no way to really express that because I don't want to misuse the site.

---

**Suggestion**

If methods of contributing and gaining reputation that don't just rely on producing new questions/answers (such as editing posts) were made more discoverable I think it would encourage more well intentioned new users to participate and thus be able to provide feedback into the site. That example might be achieved by directly suggesting it as a method of gaining initial reputation when the user tries to cast a vote and can't.

The logic being that as a new user you may strongly feel that questions/answers should be contributed out of necessity/interest and desire to help, not out of desire to gain reputation for privileges. Making you (rightly, in my opinion) reluctant to post if not necessary and not helpful.

---

**Recap**

Are there more user stories like mine where feedback on the new user experience could be being lost due to reputation requirements and, if there are, what approaches do you think could improve the situation without undermining the intentions of the privileges system?

Comment: You know you can gain up to 1000 reputation just by applying valid edits to the many badly phrased, formatted and spelt posts; just saying. As far as I'm aware the vote is registered in your total of votes (a participation metric), for which you can receive the electorate badge. (Not counted towards the OP's score of the post you've voted on though).

Comment: Why do you feel the need to engage more if the site is giving you what you want already? Some day you might become a subject matter expert in something and at that point you can give back.

Comment: 6 years and 23 reputation; if you had gained 200 reputation in that period of time then you'd have an association bonus with each site joined, allowing you basic privileges. --- Sites allow anonymous users to contribute, so they have no reputation nor can they gain any, but doing so doesn't benefit (improve) a specific account, with which you can make greater contributions; if you choose to do so. --- Each choice is voluntary, except abiding by the Code of Conduct. Lurk or work. --- Q: Edit your question to add what needs to change to accomodate your ability to contribute, or offer feedback.

Comment: @ARogueAnt. I actually wasn't aware I could gain reputation by editing posts and thought that was gated by reputation. I think that being more discoverable would address the sense of being discouraged from participating. As for the electorate badge I have checked and it looks as though votes are not counted towards it until you have gained the privilege.

Comment: @RobertLongson You make a good point, and it's part of why it has taken me so long to post a question on the matter. I was content other than the occasions where I wanted to give back in small ways (voting or providing some comment input). Until now I would just be momentarily frustrated and move on.

Comment: Fair enough about the gating, I didn't know that.

Comment: @kymkcay - If am 90% sure that fact is contained in the help center. It might be hidden behind the fact an improved edit proposal is worth 2 reputation.

Comment: Gaining reputation is not too difficult. I got 500 rep on math SE in middle school, and have a couple upvoted python answers posted on SO despite not even being halfway through the documentation. Just browse questions for a while, you’ll find something :)

Comment: I can recommend going the suggested edit route. But do rate limit yourself, especially on the smaller sites: When you see something you want to edit, add it to a list (offline or using bookmarks) instead of immediately submitting an edit and schedule it (e.g., one per day).

Comment: cont' - Also, be careful about editing old content (the [necroposting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_forum#Necroposting) response shouldn't really be there, but in reality it is, because too many people are conditioned to forums (which [Stack Exchange is not](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115))): Only edit content that has recently been on the main page (because of new answers to old questions, new questions, and new edits to other posts on a page).

Comment: cont' - Make sure to make the edits comprehensive (fix *everything*, not just your favourite nitpicks): Formatting, grammar, spelling, sufficient context for the hypothetical average future reader (links/URLs), and removing meta information (e.g. salutations). Provide a good edit summary that answers the "Why?" - especially if it is not obvious to the casual reviewer (make the reviewer's job as easy as possible - anything you can do instead of the reviewer, you should do. Don't let the reviewer guess what your intent was with the edit - say it directly).